# Sequence dependent on my place

Tags: number-sequence, language, geography, knowledge

I currently stand on point A, somewhere in Europe.

When I do my sequence here and if I start with 25, I get the following sequence:

> 25, 13, 7, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, x, ...

When I step a few metres to the Southwest,  I get the following sequence:

> 25, 10, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 5, y, ...

When I step a few metres to the East,  I get the following sequence:

> 25, 14, 8, 4, 4,  4, 4, 4, z, ...

Here $x,y,z$ are yet unknown integers, and the dots signify that the sequence continues indefinitely to the right. You may start to find $x,y,z$, but the harder question and actual puzzle is:

**Where is point A?**

Comment: Note: I changed the puzzle since I cannot count. I'm sorry to those who spent time figuring something out that is not there. Credit goes to Gordon K for noticing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Hoogste punt van Nederland](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Hoogste+punt+van+Nederland/@50.7546473,6.0207066,21z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0xdc0e1b0270fe841c)  (Highest point of the Netherlands)

The reasoning:

> Using the trusty old "count the letters in the number" technique, I have found that Dutch fits the pattern for point A:
>  25 - vijfentwintig
>  => 13 - dertien
>  => 7 - zeven
>  => 5 - vijf
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier ....

So the value for x is

> 4

Going southwest from Point A takes you to

> Belgium where the official language is French
>  25 - vingt-cinq
>  => 10 - dix
>  => 3 - trois
>  => 5 - cinq
>  => 4 - quatre
>  => 6 - six
>  => 3 - trois
>  => 5 - cinq
>  => 4 - quatre ...

So the value for y is

> 4

Stepping East takes you to

> Germany and the sequence here is
>  25 - fünfundzwanzig
>  => 14 - vierzehn
>  => 8 - acht
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier
>  => 4 - vier ...

So the value for z is

> 4

Comment: I cannot count. Sorry. The answer is correct! I wonder however why you didn't write the second sentence of the answer in English.

Comment: @wythagoras That's what Google maps calls it!

Comment: It means "Highest point of the Netherlands" by the way. I live pretty close to it :)

Comment: Unrelated, but I am amused by the fact that just to the northwest of this location is a hedge-maze, and somebody actually went to the trouble of mapping it on Google Maps...